# Why is flex item wider than container?

Tags: css, flexbox

When using flexbox, sometimes, like in the example below, when the viewport is not wide enough to contain the content, the flexbox items get higher width than the container.

- When and why does this happen?
- How can I limit the items to never be wider than the container?

Code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item-1 {
  flex: 1 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-2 {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1">
    item1item11item111item1111item11111item111111item1111111item11111111item111111111item1111111111

</div>
  <div class="item item-2">
    item2item22item222item2222item22222item222222item2222222
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a code pen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqdaoB

Answer (score 3):

try to give some space between character or give `word-break` to `.item`

```
.item {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YObyjq